# Strange constants in a PDE solution by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm solving the following PDE:

```
DSolve[F''[ξ] + (Ω^2 - 
  M^2 Exp[2 α ξ]) F[ξ] == 0, F[ξ], ξ]
```

And Mathematica gives a general solution in terms of modified Bessel functions:

$c_1\cdot\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{i\Omega}{2\alpha}}}{\Gamma(1-\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha})}I_{-\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha}}(\frac{M}{\alpha}e^{\alpha\xi})+
c_2\cdot\frac{(-1)^{\frac{i\Omega}{2\alpha}}}{\Gamma(1+\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha})}I_{\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha}}(\frac{M}{\alpha}e^{\alpha\xi})$

Rather than just:

$c_1\cdot I_{-\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha}}(\frac{M}{\alpha}e^{\alpha\xi})+
c_2\cdot I_{\frac{i\Omega}{\alpha}}(\frac{M}{\alpha}e^{\alpha\xi})$

And the latter is also a valid solution of the PDE. Any idea why these extra factors aren't absorbed into the $c$'s?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, because it doesn't have a rule for that simplification. If you want it simplified, use a rule to do that.

```
DSolve[F''[\[Xi]] + (\[CapitalOmega]^2 - 
        M^2 Exp[2 \[Alpha] \[Xi]]) F[\[Xi]] == 0, F[\[Xi]], \[Xi]][[1]] /. 
 C[n_]*z_?(FreeQ[#, \[Xi]] &) :> C[n]
```

[image]